# How to add application to facebook as a developer

Tags: facebook

I want to know how to create/add an application in Facebook as a developer?

I tried from Facebook developer, but after click create new app,  I have given app name and name space, but it shows one pop regarding you can't create app because of no authentication.  so I can't move up.  I don't know how to overcome this?

Is there any way to add an application to Facebook?

Comment: Create your app [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps), they will give you necessary info such as ` 
App ID/API Key`, `Secrete Key`, etc. which you'll need in authorizing your application with Facebook.

Comment: i tried in the link,but after i given the app name,namespace and click continue,it shows the same pop-up,even after i  given the phone no and code.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to verify your Facebook account as a developers account.

You can read about it here -  https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=167551763306531

Basically there are two options.  You can verify your account

- [via mobile phone](http://www.facebook.com/confirmphone.php)
- by [adding a credit card](https://secure.facebook.com/cards.php) to your account details.

Don't worry - they do not charge your credit card - it is only to be able to track back applications to "real" people so that they can be held accountable for "bad" apps that violate Facebook's terms of service...

Comment: I tried this,but still again showing the same,regarding not authenticate.?because of this i can't go ahead.Need to know

Comment: have you verified your account?

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I tried this,but still again showing the same,regarding not authenticate.Just i need to know,if we given a url where the application actually resides(eg:in a particular website),how it integrates to facebook.Is any registration need to my server with facebook?because of the above problem i can't go ahead.

Comment: Actually i created a seperate account.But when i tried with my account,its done.Thaks for all reply